# Qt QML accessing QML registered object in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a class which derived QObject.

```
class SerialPortWidgetBackend : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
SerialPortWidgetBackend();
QSerialPort *sp;
Q_INVOKABLE QStringList refreshPorts(void);
Q_INVOKABLE bool openPort(QString portName,QString baudRate);
Q_INVOKABLE bool closePort();
};
```

In QML file define object like this.

```
SerialPortWidgetBackend{
    id: backend
}
```

The QML file actually implements for search availible comports , cofigure it and open it. This works fine but i want access sp object. The qml registeration is below

```
qmlRegisterType<SerialPortWidgetBackend>("com.company.serialportwidgetbackend",1,0,"SerialPortWidgetBackend");
```

The registered object private.
How can access it?

Comment: Does QML really need to know about the serial port?

Comment: No it dont need. But i want open a comport. The SerialPortWidgetBackend class will used for another works.

Comment: Exactly! You do not need to access `QSerialPort` from QML.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bad practice to declare public attributes within your class. You can instead define properties with getters/setters which can be accessible from your qml file with the Q_PROPERTY Macro.

Please follow this link for more information:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html

Comment: I'd suggest to add an example of the question with suggested Q_PROPERTY

Comment: how will this answer help solve my problem?

Comment: Can you please read the documentation (i shared with you a link with all the explanation you need), i don't have it in mind..

Comment: Thank you for your answer even if this doesn't work for me

Comment: It does not make sense to make a serial port property of a class.